# How do I track explicit states for ode solvers?

Tags: matlab, closures, ode

In my derivative function, I have a list of derivatives `dy/dt` that depend on values at the current timestep. However, I have some intermediate states as well that contribute to this derivative. For example: `STATE(i)=2-RATE(i);` This is a simple example of what I mean. I would like to track the intermediate values of this state variable as well for each time point. How can this be done? These states don't have a derivative. Right now my (pseudo code)pattern is the following:

```
partition t manually
for 1:length(t)-1
  compute states(i)
  rates(i+1) = ode(dydt with updated states(i), [t(i), t(i+1)], rates(i))
end
plot rates
plot states
```

Normally, you would put all states inside the derivative function. But I would like to track it for plotting+analysis as well.

Comment: You do not. The points where the solver evaluates the ODE function have nothing (almost, and nearly never) to do with the reported values in the output. So if your ODE function is `f(t,x) = g(t,x,s(t,x))`, then the most correct way to get the values of `s` is to recompute them on the output values. // If your model has piecewise constant parameters that change under certain circumstances, then you need to use some event mechanism to stop the integration, recompute the parameter and restart the integration.

Comment: For a previous discussions on this topic, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60619524/is-there-a-way-to-output-intermediate-calculations, there is, after all, not that much helpful content on "[ode] intermediate" in the search results. I had the impression that I wrote more on this topic.